# Run a ant scripts for a project that depends on other project

Tags: java, ant, junit

I am new for apache ant. Now, I am trying to run a single ant for two project. Lets see below....

I have a project named 'Multiply'. In that project, I write a java class named 'Multiply' and a function named 'multiply' that multiply two input integer and return result.

And then I created another project named 'Multiply-Test'. In build path configuration, I add 'Multiply' project into it to test. And then I write a Test class named 'MultiplyTest' and a test case that test return value of multiply function of Multiply class of Multiply Project.

And then I write a ant script (build.xml) file for 'Multiply-Test' project. My xml file is....

```
<!-- Sets variables which can later be used. -->
<property name="src.dir" location="src" />
<property name="build.dir" location="bin" />
<property name="test.report.dir" location="test-result" />

<!-- Define the classpath which includes the junit.jar and the classes after compiling-->
<path id="junit.class.path">
    <pathelement location="lib/junit.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${build.dir}" />
</path>

<!-- Deletes the existing build, docs and dist directory-->
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${test.report.dir}" />
</target>

<!-- Creates the  build, docs and dist directory-->
<target name="makedir">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${test.report.dir}" />
</target>

<!-- Compiles the java code (including the usage of library for JUnit -->
<target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir">
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}/com/dat/multiply" destdir="${build.dir}">
        <classpath refid="junit.class.path" />
    </javac>
</target>

<!-- Run the JUnit Tests -->
<target name="junit" depends="compile">
    <junit printsummary="on" fork="true" haltonfailure="yes">
        <classpath refid="junit.class.path" />
        <formatter type="xml" />
        <batchtest todir="${test.report.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <include name="**/*Test.java" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>

<target name="main" depends="compile, junit">
    <description>Main target</description>
</target>
```

And then I run ant script. I found the following error in console....

```
 Buildfile: C:\Eclipse Kepler\workspace\Multiply-Test\build.xml 
 clean:  
    [delete] Deleting directory C:\Eclipse Kepler\workspace\Multiply-Test\bin 
    [delete] Deleting directory C:\Eclipse Kepler\workspace\Multiply-Test\test-tesult 
 makedir: 
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Eclipse Kepler\workspace\Multiply-Test\bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Eclipse Kepler\workspace\Multiply-Test\test-result
 compile:
    [javac] C:\Eclipse Kepler\workspace\Multiply-Test\build.xml:29: 
    warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
junit:
    [junit] Running com.dat.test.MultiplyTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec

    BUILD FAILED
    C:\Eclipse Kepler\workspace\Multiply-Test\build.xml:36: Test com.dat.test.MultiplyTest failed

    Total time: 1 second
```

And found the following junit output error......

```
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.dat.test.MultiplyTest
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
```

But I test by another way. That, and then, I clean and build both project. And then run 'MultiplyTest' class  by Right click on class -> Run As. -> JUnit Test. Oh, It is work really. And Junit result is true that i wish.

Now, I don't know how to do for work that test class from ant scripts. I need to solve, but I don't know.
Anybody help me. Thanks..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look right:

```
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}/com/dat/multiply" destdir="${build.dir}">
    <classpath refid="junit.class.path" />
</javac>
```

The `srcdir` of `<javac>` shouldn't include the `/com/dat/multiply` part. The [`<javac>` documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html#srcdirnote) explains:

> Do not include part of your package structure in the srcdir attribute

Instead, it should be:

```
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}">
    <classpath refid="junit.class.path" />
</javac>
```